Data analysis of points In polygon
Here's what I have for a project being completed in QGIS:

Layer 1 - Shapefile of all 50 US states
Layer 2 - CSV of commodity producer data.  Each entry includes spatial location (lat/long).

The CSV was successfully loaded into the project.  Using rule-based symbology, I've broken the data down into 28 total symbols on the map (27 using the categories/parameters I wanted plus 1 additional for "everything else".  "Everything else" in this CSV is just bad data and is ignored.
In short the data is classified as follows

3 types of commodities,
3 types of "facilities"
and 3 status types (Active, Idle, or Closed), resulting in the 27 categories.

From here, I want to do an analysis.  Basically, I want to select one of the 27 categories and have QGIS do a count of the points in that category within each state.  And then repeat that with the remaining 26 categories.  I've found the "Count Points in Polygon" command under the Vector menu but it only returns the total points within each state, ignoring the categorization.

you could use select by expression, and then check the selected only box in the count function

You'll get a long format table but if that is OK:
Create a virtual layer:
select  a.State_Name, 
        concat(b.commodity, '-', b.facility, '-', b.status) as category, 
        count(*) as count
from States_shapefile as a
left join pointLayer as b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
group by a.State_Name, category

Replace State_name, commodity, facility, status with your fieldnames, and States_shapefile and pointLayer with your layernames.

